# Naruto's surname confusion

Tags: naruto

Naruto's father's name is Minato Namikaze, and mother is Kushina Uzumaki.
So, why is Naruto's surname Uzumaki? Shoudn't it be Namikaze?

Comment: My guess, but i'm guessing the third didn't want him growing up as son of the hero that died. Also, if his name was Namikaze Naruto, it would give away that he's the son of the hero that died wouldn't it? ;D Not as interesting that way.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember it now. The third didn't want to know him of his father. That's right. Thanhks @ton yeung

Comment: Wouldn't people think differently of Minato had they known Naruto was his son? Naruto was ostracized in the village because he had the 9 Tails sealed in him so it shows the kind of opinion people had with whoever ended up being the 9 Tails host, and i don't think a "hero" is the kind of person who would force that kind of fate on their own child unless they were an ass, not saying Minato was but his sacrifice may have had a different meaning otherwise

Comment: @Memor-X I don't think it's about 'image' of Minato. In my opinion 3rd wanted treat him like 'normal kid'. Ofcourse he wasn't normal, cause of 9 Tails inside him. Hmmm.. maybe it was said somethere but really remember :(

Comment: It's the trend. Bleach's Kurosaki Ichigo has his family name, Kurosaki, from his mother, not his father.

Answer (score 7):

In Naruto "Ch.440: A Conversation with the 4th" it is stated that the third Hokage wanted as little information about the Kyuubi out in public as possible and that's why nobody, not even Naruto should know that Minato was his father. Thus he was given the name Uzumaki instead of Namikaze.

Page 5: "If anyone knew you were my son, you'd have been in constant danger"